# Asp .Net, sorting grid view error

Tags: c#, asp.net

On click of the Email fiend in my gridview, nothing happens. Here is my code. Please help. New to asp .net.

**I HAVE SET ONSORT = "gvdetails_Sorting" and SORTING =TRUE**

**FRONT END :**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Id">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email_Id") %>'
            Wrap="true" Width="100%" SortExpression="Email_Id">
        </asp:Label>                                         
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**Back End :**

```
#region "Properties"
public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}
#endregion




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }

}

protected void BindGrid()
{
     try
    {
    Agent_Supervisor_Email obj = new Agent_Supervisor_Email();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = obj.FillGrid();
    gvdlist.DataSource = ds;
    gvdlist.DataBind();
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ExceptionHandle(ex);
     }
}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    try
    {
        if ((ViewState["Data"] != null))
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv = (DataView)ViewState["Data"];
            dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + direction;
            gvdlist.DataSource = dv;
            gvdlist.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandle(ex);
    }
}
```

OTHER CODE IN BETWEEN. THEN FOLLOWING CODE.

```
 protected void gvdlist_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, "DESC");
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, "ASC");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandle(ex);
    }
}
```

IT DOES NOT GIVE ME ANY ERROR. BUT MY CODE SEEMS TO DO NOTHING.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `gvdlist_Sorting`, is it hit when you sort the GridView? What's the value of `dv` after the line `dv = (DataView)ViewState["Data"];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check that you are setting the GridView properties for OnSorting and AllowSorting correctly:

```
OnSorting="gvdlist_Sorting" AllowSorting="true"
```

2) As mentioned by Markus, check if the ViewState["Data"] actually contains your data. As you haven't posted the code that sets the ViewState["Data"], perhaps you are not setting it anywhere and so your sorting code will not actually be run.